# MySql Ñ character when importing from csv file

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to import a csv file to a table, the names in the csv file contains the character 'Ñ'. Once the importing is done all 'Ñ' characters are replaced by � and it gives me errors when I apply changes.

I can replace it 1 by 1 but there's 247 of them.

If it's possible is there anyway I can import the file using a syntax where I can add something like Replace all � with Ñ

edit: I'm just using mysql workbench.

Thanks.

Comment: You have an encoding problem, but without more specifics it will be hard for someone here to diagnose it accurately.  It is likely your input data is CP-1252 encoded and the database is UTF-8.  However it could also be the program you are using to display the data.  Without seeing the actual bits and database configuration it's hard to tell.

Comment: I'm using MySql Workbench